# Graphing the landscape

Tags: tensorflow, graph, neural-network

Given a neural network structure in TensorFlow, is there a way to plot a graph, not of the network structure but of the fitness landscape? That is, tuples of possible weight values versus the corresponding cost function? Ideally with a line indicating the path a training run followed through the landscape.

(In general there are more than two weights; that means any applicable tricks would have to be used for a best effort at squashing a higher dimensional landscape down to a 2-D screen.)

Comment: I don't think tf has this feature. If you know which set of parameters you care, you can add scalar summary for them (say, weight w1 and w2) at training time together with the cost function. Then after training is done, you look at the event file logged for the three summaries (w1, w2, and cost) and use the global step to join them get a four column data file (   step, w1, w2, cost) At this time, you could use whatever tools to plot the trajectory of cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now there is. I don't know how to squash several dimensions down to a 2-D display and still have it readable, but I've put together some code that plots the fitness landscape for two variables while holding the others constant:

https://github.com/russellw/tf-examples/blob/master/landscape.py